# Convert date from dd.mm.yyyy format to dd-mmm-yyyy

Tags: excel, vba, date

Recently I've been trying to write a macro code for converting a range of dates in dd.mm.yyyy to dd-mmm-yyyy format.
So, I first replaced the `"."` with `"-"` and used `numberformat = dd-mmm-yyyy`
There seems to be an error in the output as it is giving month as date and date as month, e.g., `07.01.2020` is showing as `01-Jul-2020`.

Following is the code:

```
sub dateformat()

 range("A2").replace what:="." replacement:="-"
 range("A2").numberformat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"

end sub
```

Kindly help if there's a solution to this.

Comment: If `A2` really contains a date then ` range("A2").replace what:="." replacement:="-"` should not have any effect and it is not necessary at all . If it has an effect then `A2` is a text cell and you need to convert it to a date first.

Comment: A2 is saved in general format. The code is replacing "." to "-" and then converting it to date format. Here is an example of the output Jul-01-20
Jul-01-20
21-02-2020
17-03-2020
27-03-2020
It is converting 07-01-2020 to 01-Jul-2020 but not the rest. How do I convert to date first?

Comment: If `A2` were set to `general format` you should see `43837` if if contained a date.

Comment: Please read up on how Excel handles dates before continuing this conversation. This link will be as good as any and better than some. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm. Then tell us whether your dates are true dates or fake dates - both as they are and as you want them. True dates, as you will learn, are numbers which you can display in whichever way you want. Fake dates are text strings which can't be used in calculations.

Comment: @Variatus: Yes, right. It seems OP first needs to do this otherwise my comments will seem like greek to him.

Comment: It's a fake date. In general format it's showing as 07.01.2020. I would want it to be shown as 07-Jan-2020. Is there a way to convert this string to an actual date?

Comment: First [convert it fo a date](https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/vba-convert-string-to-date-with-cdate/) and then apply the numberformat

Comment: Exactly how did the dates get there?  Manual input?  Text or CSV file import?  Frequently it is better to correct the problem at the time of data input, then to try to correct things after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub fixdate()
    Dim s As String
    With Range("A2")
        s = .Text
        .Clear
        .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        .Value = DateSerial(Right(s, 4), Mid(s, 4, 2), Left(s, 2))
      End With
End Sub
```